# Is there a way to find out if Plesk is having problems?

Tags: email, plesk

I run 2 websites, and their emails, on a VPS.  I use Outlook for the email needs. 
 Recently, I sent out 6 emails.  5 of them went through with the last one getting stuck in Outlook's Outbox.  The error code I received, was:  0x80042109.

I am able to continue receiving emails but cannot send out any emails, since the error with the batch of 6 emails.  I cannot seem to see any errors on the server and I have not changed any settings in Outlook.  I have tried sending emails, via Outlook on differing devices to no success.  I am able to use Gmail and Hotmail fine.

I have also changed Ports etc but, again, to no success.

As such, I am thinking there may be a problem with Plesk itself.  Is there a way to check whether Plesk is experiencing problems at the moment?

Comment: You can look at the [mail server log](https://talk.plesk.com/threads/how-do-i-view-mail-logs.74135/) to see what's transpired. Often just restarting the [mail service](https://talk.plesk.com/threads/mails-in-queue-cant-be-sent.342272/), or the server itself, helps to clear things out. Since you're running your own mail server, you might have delivery issues depending on who you're sending to (e.g., it might be being blocked by an ISP/email provider), which can hold up other emails sometimes. Try the restart, or manually clear it out of the queue if need be.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Dan.  The issue seemed to had resolved itself overnight.  I will keep your suggestion in mind, should the issue occur again, to see if it will 'force through' the fix rather than waiting for it to 'sort itself out'.  Thanks, once again.